# Reproduce the same result of the C++ 11 random generator

Tags: c++, c++11, random, mt19937

Is it guaranteed by the standard that if `std::mt19937` was seeded by the same number, it will produce the same sequence of numbers on all platforms?

In other words, is its implementation well-defined by the standard or it is like `std::rand()` which was considered as implementation details?

Comment: I think it is implementation defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [[rand.eng.mars]](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.eng.mers) 1-5 the passage basically sums up the implementation details for the [mersenne twister algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

`std::mt19937` is just a typedef for

```
using mt19937 =
      mersenne_twister_engine<uint_fast32_t,
       32,624,397,31,0x9908b0df,11,0xffffffff,7,0x9d2c5680,15,0xefc60000,18,1812433253>;
```

And all the standard says about the expected results is that :

> Required behavior: The 10000 th consecutive invocation of a
>   default-constructed object of type mt19937 shall produce the value
>   4123659995.

No other guarantees are made.

However, because the `std::mersenne_twister_engine` is required to follow the mersenne twister PRNG implementation it's implementation *is* well defined.

Comment: for someone unfamiliar with the random generator algorithms (like me) this sounds like a very very strange requirement.

Comment: @bolov read 1-5 in rand.eng.mars, that's basically a summary of the implementation of the mersenne twister PRNG.

Comment: @bolov This requirement is not really useful since the behavior of `std::mersenne_twister_engine` and its default seed are already well-defined by the standard.

Comment: @bolov - it does sound strange, but it's a very handy check when you're implementing the algorithm.